# Project stops working after installing signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr

After I install signalr to my project and try to run the project I have this error message

[image]

Error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: The error says runtime is missing the Newtonsoft.Json dll in the bin directory. Check for that dll if you have that in your bin directory with the correct version (4.5.0.0 in your case).

Comment: Is JSON.Net package installed?

Comment: That error typically means that a assembly that you uses are tying to use another version than the one that was loaded into your appdomain.The error is usually resolved by adding an <assemblyBinding>.

Comment: I found Newtonsoft.Json dll in bin directory, but it version is (6.0.4.17603). How to resolve this problem ? how can I use <assemblyBinding> to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I search in the Internet for any solution, I didn't find any solution.
The only way that solve the problem is to install old version of signalr.
I install version 2.1.0. This version doesn't change the version of Newtonsoft.Json.
Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall Newtonsoft.Json dll again,  SignalR installs an old version of Newtonsoft.Json dll, and make sure that your web config file references the newer verion.

Comment: I try reinstalling Newtonsoft.Json, but the problem not solved.

Comment: Make sure that your web.Config is referenceing version 6 not 4.5, also make sure that your project packages are not referencing v 4.5, only v6.

Comment: I do what you say, but nothing change.

In web.Config, I add this :
  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.7"/>
      </dependentAssembly>

And In packages, I found this reference :
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.7" targetFramework="net451" />

Comment: Where did you get 6.0.7 from? I think it should be 6.0.0, the worst case uninstall newtonsoft.json and reinstall it again.

Comment: 6.0.7 is the newer version. And I uninstall and reinstall but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the error you meant (I remember encountering this as well but that was quite some time ago).

Try adding the following

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

under

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
....
```

in your hub's web.config file and try

Comment: Can you check the version of your newtonsoft and ensure its within the range of 4.0 - 6.0.7?